# Rewrite plex media server url on nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have very limited knowledge with rewriting url in nginx. I have a plex media server running behind on nginx, i can access the dashboard with http://domain.com/web/index.html with these config i found on github:

```
upstream plex-upstream {
    server plex-server.example.com:32400;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name domain.com

    location / {
                if ($http_x_plex_device_name = '') {
                      rewrite ^/$ http://$http_host/web/index.html;
}

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_redirect off;

                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://plex-upstream;
}
}
```

What i want is to remove /web/index.html so when i go to http://domain.com, the PMS dashboard will load. I tried some one liner rewrite rules already but all failed. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

I am not nginx specialist, but I had similar problem.
The diference is that I was not trying to alias domain.name/ to domain.name/web/,
My goal was to alias domain.name/plex/ to domain.name/web/.
I was getting redirects to web/index.html with all solutions I could find except this one [Configure Plex Media Server Reverse Proxy nginx Linux](https://www.htpcguides.com/configure-plex-media-server-reverse-proxy-nginx-linux/).

The only one problem with this one was that if you go to web/ you will stay there.

So here is my creepy yet working solution:

```
upstream plex {
    server localhost:32400;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.name;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        # Enables WS support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /web/index.html {
      if ($http_x_should_not_redirect = ""){
        return 301 https://domain.name/plex/index.html;
      }

      proxy_pass https://plex;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header x_should_not_redirect $host;
    }

    location /web {
      proxy_pass https://plex;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header x_should_not_redirect $host;
    }

    location /plex {
      proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1/web;
      proxy_set_header X-should-not-redirect $host; 
    }



    location /transmission/rpc {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9091;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        # Enables WS support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;
    }


    location /transmission/web {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9091;

        proxy_pass_header  X-Transmission-Session-Id;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # Enables WS support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dovgastreetnas.viewdns.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dovgastreetnas.viewdns.net/privkey.pem;       # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  }
```

Hope this will help somebody.